# Class of $p_i$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{p_i} = l$ for some $l$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory

Let $l$ be any integer and $p_i$ belong to natural numbers for $1 \leq i \leq n$. Suppose they satisfy the following equation $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{p_i} = l$$ Suppose we are given $l$ and $n$ is fixed. What can we conculde about $p_i$? More specifically, can we say any class of $p_i$ which statisfies the above equation. Or Is there any we can say explicitly which $p_i$ satifies the equation.

Comment: What is your question really ? When we are free to make $n$ as large as we want then given $p_1,\ldots,p_j$ there is a solution $p_1,\ldots,p_{j+l}$ iff $\sum_{i \le j}1/p_i \le l$. When $n$ is fixed there is an algorithm to enumerate all the solutions.

Comment: @reuns, when $n$ is fixed, is there an algorithm to find all the solutions..

Comment: What do you not understand ?

Answer (score -1):

> Given $n,l$ enumerate all the $p_1\le p_2\le \ldots \le p_n$ such that $$l=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{p_i}$$

Due to the $\le$ restriction given $p_1\ldots p_{j-1}$ we must have $p_j\le \frac{n-j}{l-\sum_{i=1}^{j-1} \frac1{p_i}}$. This gives the naive algorithm :

- Starting with $j=1$
- If $j\le n$ let $r=\sum_{i=1}^{j-1} \frac1{p_i}$

  - If $r=l$ then return
  - Otherwise for each $p_j\le \frac{n-j}{l-r}$, enumerate recursively the solutions $p_{j+1}\le \ldots \le p_n$
- If $j=n+1$

  - if $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{p_i} \ne l$ then return
  - otherwise enumerate all the permutations of $p_1,\ldots,p_n$